# is there an easy way to convert 3d Model .DWG to .gltf or STL format with color?

Tags: 3d, autocad, autodesk-model-derivative

trying to convert DWG to gltf or glb , couldnt find a way directly ! ,I tried to export the model to STL directly but model always came in Gray color !
I tried to look for forge tools using VScode and I couldnt understand how do the conversion I was only able to see the model uploaded to hub .
do you know easy library to deal with or some online convertor , maybe guide me through steps I might be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you performed translation https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-to-stl/ before viewing.

List of all supported translation https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/

Answer (score 0):

Direct conversion is almost impossible if the objects in DWG are not actually 3D meshes but solids.
The only way how I could do it:

- convert all solids to meshes in AutoCAD using MESHSMOOTH command and then MESHSMOOTHLESS to fix the oversmoothing
- export as FBX (choose Visible Entities and mark only Objects, if don't need lights and lots of other stuff)
- convert FBX to gltf or glb using Blender or https://github.com/facebookincubator/FBX2glTF tool. A caveat - it depends on FBX version! If your AutoCAD is old, it will export older FBX version that's not supported by Blender and many other tools.